# How does AspNetCore inject css and js into its developer exception page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

The error page found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.6/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/Views/ErrorPage.cshtml) is using the code below to inject css and js files into the cshtml file.

What is responsible for replacing the include tags with the actual css and js?

```html
<style>
    <%$ include: Error.css % >
</style>
```

Comment: Looking at the file structure in that link, it seems that just having the css file in the same directory of the error page (CompilationErrorPage.cshtml) does the trick.

Comment: @AndréSilva that's not the case. I tried doing the same thing in a different view and my css and js files don't get injected. Inspecting the view in the browser just shows the include tags in plain text.

Comment: I feel like they're cheating here. This amounts to essentially a server-side include, but the ability to do that in Razor in ASP.NET Core is not documented anywhere. I'd imagine they're doing some sort of custom preprocessing of this view as part of the middleware.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm assuming the same. I downloaded the source code yesterday and tried to find out where, however i didn't find any hints for that.

Comment: The same conclusion is what brought me to SO. It looks like whatever auto-generated the ErrorPage.Designer.cs class was able to inject the css and js but I can't seem to find what is generating that designer class. I've tried switching the class to an aspx to generate the designer but am so far unsuccessful.

Comment: @ChrisPratt

Yeah, this appears to be all custom preprocessing. To get my own error page to work, I did the following.

1) Set my view's build action to Content, then compile
2) Decompile the *.views.dll and copy my view's razor code into a new view.Designer.cs class
3) Add new files for AttributeValue, BaseView, and HelperResult from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics
4) Remove all the tag helper code in my view.Designer.cs class and inherit from BaseView
5) Copy my css and js into the new view.Designer.cs class
6) Add my own middle-ware and call app.UseMyExceptionPage() in Startup.cs

Comment: I don't think I'll keep this exact implementation for my specific purpose but figured I would share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling down a little farther to read the readme on AspNetCore Diagnostics brought me to the answer. They are using a custom tool to generate the razor code and inject css/js. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src

> Diagnostics middleware like DeveloperExceptionPage uses compiled Razor views. After updating the *.cshtml file you must run the RazorPageGenerator tool to generate an updated compiled Razor view.
>
> Run the following command in AspNetCore-Tooling\src\Razor\src\RazorPageGenerator:
>
> dotnet run Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.RazorViews path-to-aspnetcore-middleware-diagnostics-src